# Showing/hiding items based on linkbutton click in ASP Web Form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have been trying to get this code to work, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I have a LinkButton in a GridView, which I click, that populates another GridView and a Repeater. My issue lies with the items below the second GridView. I've got two LinkButtons, a Label, and a TextBox which I need hidden until the second gridview is displayed. So far I have tried setting "Visible = false" and switching to true in the code behind once the LinkButton is clicked, but nothing displays, I have tried turning off validation and some other things as well but no luck so far, this was the last thing I tried:

Web form code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ReceivingPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Receiving_ReceivingPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<h1 class="well">Receiving</h1>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODSOpenPOList" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetOpenPO" TypeName="eToolsSystem.BLL.ReceiveController"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ODSOpenPOList">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PurchaseOrderID" HeaderText="Order" SortExpression="PurchaseOrderID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="Order Date" SortExpression="OrderDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="VendorName" HeaderText="Vendor" SortExpression="VendorName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Contact Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# "ReceivingPage.aspx?id="+Eval("PurchaseOrderID") %>' CausesValidation="True" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">View Order</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODSPopulatePOItemList" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetPOItemByPurchaseOrderID" TypeName="eToolsSystem.BLL.ReceiveController">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="purchaseOrderId" QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODSVendorByID" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetVendorByID" TypeName="eToolsSystem.BLL.ReceiveController">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="purchaseOrderId" QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<br />
<asp:Repeater ID="VendorRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="ODSVendorByID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        PO #<%# Eval("PurchaseOrderID") %>Vendor: <%# Eval("VendorName") %>
        Contact Phone:<%# Eval("Phone") %>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:GridView ID="ReceiverPanel" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ODSPopulatePOItemList">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StockItemID" HeaderText="StockItemID" SortExpression="StockItemID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantityOnOrder" HeaderText="QuantityOnOrder" SortExpression="QuantityOnOrder" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantityOutstanding" HeaderText="Outstanding" SortExpression="QuantityOutstanding" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Receive" Visible="True">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Received" Text='<%# Eval("Received") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Return">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Returned" Text='<%# Eval("ReturnedQuantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reason">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Reason" Text='<%# Eval("Reason") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="PurchaseOrderDetailID" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("PurchaseOrderDetailID") %>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="PurchaseOrderID" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("PurchaseOrderID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:LinkButton ID="ReceiveButton" runat="server" OnClick="ReceiveButton_Click" Visible="false">Receive</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="ForceClose" runat="server" OnClick="ForceClose_Click" Visible="false">Force Close</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Label ID="ReasonLabel" runat="server" Text="Reason:" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="ForceCloseTextBox" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ForceClose.Visible = true;
    ReceiveButton.Visible = true;
    ReasonLabel.Visible = true;
    ForceCloseTextBox.Visible = true;
}
```

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your pageload  code?

Comment: the page load is just empty currently.

Comment: Does the code behind `LinkButton1_Click` execute?

Comment: I don't have your object data sources so I can't run the code but I created a button and added the line ForceClose.Visible = true; to the click event and the link showed up fine for me. I would suggest narrowing down to the problem a little more.

Comment: I think my issue is that I set things up s it's passing by a query string... Not sure how I'd set up this LinkButton as anything else right now thoughI need it to pass a specific value when I click the button to another gridview on my page..